# insert into for all users who are in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables (notifications and following). I want to add notifications for all users who are following this page. For only one user i do like this:

```
INSERT INTO notifications ( from_id , to_id , type, checked, page_id ) VALUES ( :from_id , :to_id , :type, :checked, :page_id)
```

And i want to do the same but for the all users who is following the same page. 
important points: page_id points the page and to_id points the users.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notifications` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`type` int(11) NOT NULL,
`checked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=122 ;

 -----

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `following` (
`following_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`accepted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`following_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`following_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=82 ;
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `insert . . . select` syntax for inserting multiple rows from the same table.  I'm not sure exactly what columns you want from where, but here is the approach:

```
INSERT INTO notifications(from_id, to_id, type, checked, page_id) 
    select f.follower_id, :to_id, :type, :checked, f.page_id
    from following f
    where f.page_id = :page_id;
```